# Why is VTK_INIT_MODULE([...]) needed in a QT application with QVTKWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, qvtkwidget

I started trying out the VTK with QT. I've set up everything with cmake and as Compiler VS15(x64) and thought I just can use stuff like the QVTKWidget in a QT application without needing to specify additional stuff beside of headers and library linking(used qtdesigner with vtk plugin so it's just a sample application).

However, it was needed to use things like this so that a simple GUI with a QVTKWidget started:

```
#include <vtkAutoInit.h>
VTK_INIT_MODULE(vtkRenderingOpenGL2)
VTK_INIT_MODULE(vtkInteractionStyle)
```

Did I configured vtk wrong or did I misunderstood something? Please explain it to me =)!
If there's already such a question then please bear with me I tried to find a answer with Google and also searched on stackoverflow.

Comment: My recommendation is to use `CMake` with your application and avoid all the complicated initialization and setup.

Comment: I haven't used CMake in my applications yet because I haven't learned how to code Cmake files. But if this is the appropriate way I'll try this way :)